# Three.js shadows not working properly

Tags: three.js, shadow, light

I was trying to learn about shadows in Three.js and I found [this nice example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSt8c/). 
However I am not able to understand why, when I lower the y of light to like 65, that is:

```
light.position.set( 20, 65, 0 );
```

the shadow disappears completely.
Meanwhile, everything above 70 is perfectly fine and the shadow is cast. Like always, I am probably missing something obvious, but I really cannot see what can be preventing the light from making that shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
```

To see the position and direction of the light on screen this will help you to understand what is changing.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of how you do this? I tried this line, but nothing changed. And I thought the "sun" shows where the light goes. Or doesn't it?

Comment: I am starting to realize that I should be using SpotLight. Already found a few examples of it myself, so your example proves me I'm on the right way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because shadows will only be cast by and onto objects inside the frustrum of the `light.shadowCamera`; in this case, the default `light.shadowCameraNear` appears to be set to about `50`, so the frustrum begins too far from the light source, and when the light's `position.y` is at `65` the bar isn't included. When the light's `position.y` is `70`, the closest edge of the `shadowCamera` frustrum moves up to include the bar, and the shadow is cast properly.

You can fix this by setting `light.shadowCameraNear` to a smaller number. In that fiddle, uncomment the line:

```
light.shadowCameraNear = 1;
```

and the shadow will appear no matter how low you move the light.